# Change directory to SBT project in IntelliJ with SBT console

Tags: intellij-idea, sbt

I've just installed [SBT plugin](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/?id=5007) for IntelliJ and successfully imported my project. SBT console in IntelliJ shows up as expected, however I can't use it because of layout of my project. The entire problem is that my SBT Play! project is not a top-level directory. Instead I have maven parent pom with several child modules amongst which my SBT application is placed. This is how it looks like:

```
MyProject (parent pom)
-> submodule1 (JAR)
-> submodule2 (JAR)
-> webapp (SBT Play! webapp module)
```

There is no problem to run Play! application from Linux CLI, previously changing directory to `MyProject\webapp` and executing SBT from there. However, I don't see any option to set root dir for SBT console in IntelliJ. I have entire project imported into workspace, so the default project root directory is `MyProject` which is obviously not treaded as SBT project.

Is there any way to change "working directory" for IntelliJ SBT plugin?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, here's how I got it going:

1. Start by adding your root as a new module.  In your case it will MyProject.  I was careful to add this as a blank module, but if you already have something like a pom file (which begs the question as to why you want to use SBT), then you might be okay letting IntelliJ import it for you.
2. Next, add a scala file to your root project directory to map the sub-projects.  A great explanation on how to set one of these up can be found on the [scala wiki](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.3/docs/Getting-Started/Multi-Project.html)

> import sbt._
>       import Keys._
>
> ```
> object HelloBuild extends Build {
>     lazy val root = Project(id = "MyProject",
>                             base = file(".")) aggregate(submodule1, submodule2, webapp)    
>
> lazy val submodule1 = Project(id = "submodule1",
>                            base = file("submodule1"))
>
>     lazy val submodule2 = Project(id = "submodule2",
>                            base = file("submodule2"))
>
>     lazy val webapp = Project(id = "webapp",
>                            base = file("webapp"))
>
> }
> ```

1. Start your SBT and you should now be able to switch between projects.  If you have it up and running, make sure you use the `reload` command to apply the changes.

You can list the projects SBT recognizes as modules with the `projects` command.  Switch projects by using `project [projectName]`.  So to switch to submodule2, just type `project submodule2.`